# NODE N-API When using functions from addon blocks the main process node js?

Tags: node.js, node.js-addon, node-nan

Implemented a wrapper for the function using N-API. It works, but the problem is that when it works the main thread of the node does not work? How can I rewrite this function so that it does not block the main thread? What do I need to use async, callback, thread for this?

```
napi_value readDataSerial(napi_env env, napi_callback_info info) {
        napi_status status;
        size_t argc = 1;    
        napi_value args[1], object;  
        napi_value id, data;
        status = napi_get_cb_info(env, info, &argc, args, NULL, NULL);
        assert(status == napi_ok);
        if (argc < 1) {
          napi_throw_type_error(env, NULL, "Wrong number of arguments");
          return NULL;
        }    
        //....
        Ibox_ReadData *context = calloc(1, sizeof(Ibox_Context));
        //this function takes a long time and blocks the main process
        Ibox_Result_Submit *submitResult = Ibox_Controller_ReadData(context);
        status = napi_create_object(env, &object);
        status = napi_create_string_utf8(env, submitResult->id, NAPI_AUTO_LENGTH, &id);
        status = napi_set_named_property(env, object, "id", id);         
        status = napi_create_string_utf8(env, submitResult->date, NAPI_AUTO_LENGTH, &date);
        status = napi_set_named_property(env, object, "data", data);         
        assert(status == napi_ok);
        return object;
    })
```

Comment: To be fair: JS has only ever been single threaded. If you need parallelism rather than merely asynchronous task execution, you're going to either have to use [workers threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) or if you _can_ outsource the work, spawn a new process. For example, have a dedicated script that wraps the native api stuff, and "talk" to that by invocation it with runtime args and reading its stdout on completion; or have an HTTP server veneer that lets you perform REST calls from other scripts. Or even a websocket server that lets you run socket communication, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's not trivial, but this [example](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/tree/main/src/5-async-work/async_pi_estimate/node-addon-api) shows how to create an async worker thread and return results without blocking.